# Are bookings needed to visit Austrian vineyards?

Tags: bookings, austria, alcohol

My spouse and I are planning to visit Austria in August. We would be probably be flying and staying in Wien, as it's easy to get a direct flight + hotel package there. Wien would serve as our base of operations for the visit.

We would like to visit the wine country surrounding Wien at Niederösterreich. Our plan would be to visit different vineyards and attend wine tastings and buy bottles of local wine to bring back home.

Are Austrian vineyards open for visitation, or do we need to book appointments beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [calendar of events](https://veranstaltungen.niederoesterreich.at) for Niederösterreich, albeit it looks like it's in German only. You can select events by category, e.g.

- [wine tastings (Degustation, Verkostung)](https://veranstaltungen.niederoesterreich.at/?MainCategory=52&SubCategory=55&sort=dateonly)
- [wine festivals (Weinfest, Kellergassenfest)](https://veranstaltungen.niederoesterreich.at/?MainCategory=52&SubCategory=61&sort=dateonly)

For translations, try [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator).

A random vineyard with guided tours and tasting:

> [Weinschauen am Weingut Sonnenhügel](https://veranstaltungen.niederoesterreich.at/127858/weinschauen-am-weingut-sonnenhgel) (translated by DeepL)
>
> Before the wine tasting, take a look at the vineyard together with us and get to know the different facets of our winery! It is a pleasure for us to be able to tell you personally what is important to us in vineyard maintenance and vinification. We would be happy to serve bread and to cater for your preferences in the selection of wines.
>
> Price pP € 8,- (incl. tasting of 6 wines). Duration approx. 1.5 hours. Registration required. 6. Apr. - 26. Okt. 2019, Saturday: 16:00 Uhr

Many vineyards have their own shop or even guest rooms, which might be an alternative to a hotel in Wien.

For more information, I'd recommend to contact the tourist information of some villages in the area you are interested in. You can also call/mail [weinviertel.at](https://www.weinviertel.at/en).

Comment: Nice answer. Teach a man to fish!